# "argument type mismatch" error when trying to send an email from excel Userform

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I have this set in my general definitions-

```
Public Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Plain(strbody As String)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        'Send to Manager email entry when ready to go live
        .To = ""
        .CC = "" 
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "There was an error/best practice found in" & Me.txtJobNumber
        .Body = strbody
        .Display   
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

And then under the command button sub I have these two lines of code:

```
Content = "This is the body of the email"     
Call Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Plain(Content)
```

The error highlights the word content and tells me that it is **Compile error:ByRef argument type mismatch.**

I have tried to "set Content=" and I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare Content before you use it.

```
Dim Content As String
Content = "This is the body of the email"
Call Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Plain(Content)
```

This can happen if you are not using "Option Explicit".  Adding that at the very top of your code (above all subs and functions), will require you to declare your variables.  If variables are not declared, VB will guess and you will run into these sorts of issues.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Content As String
    Content = "This is the body of the email"
    Call Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Plain(Content)
End Sub

Public Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Plain(strbody As String)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        'Send to Manager email entry when ready to go live
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "There was an error/best practice found in " & Trim(Str(Me.txtJobNumber))
        .body = strbody
        .display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```